# Map property of an object of object trimming the name property if its too long

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Given an object like this:

```
 var fullObj = {
  prop1: "myProp1",
  subobject: {
    Obj1_id: {
      id: "Obj3_id",
      name: "./",
      otherProperties:...
    },
    Obj2_id: {
      id: "Obj2_id",
      name: "Obj2_id",
      ...
    },
    Obj3_id: {
      id: "Obj3_id",
      name: "Obj3",
     ....
    },
```

I would like to trim the name if it is too long(more than myLength) plus 3 dots
I know like to use something like that otherwise just the name

```
name=name.substr(0,myLength)+"..."
```

Given that this object is in a react state how can I manipulate the state (using  class based component)?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for. It will check if the value of `name` is greater then 3 then it will take the first 3 letters from the `name` and add `...` in it.

```
Object.keys(fullObj.subobject).forEach(function(key) {
    if(fullObj.subobject[key].name.length > 3){
        fullObj.subobject[key].name = fullObj.subobject[key].name.slice(0,3) + "..."
    }
});
```